# while loop is using if part not elif part?

Tags: python

I am trying to code a hang man game where it hides the letters of a word and it replaces each letter once you guess that certain letter.

When I get a wrong answer, I want to put it into a list which I can print and show the user the count of wrong letters (so I can do hangman drawing).

I can get it to go into a list once and then once I do a correct letter it does not work the first time and I must reinput the correct letter again. I then go to a wrong letter, it no longer works and I get an error:

> ValueError: substring not found - position = (word.index(guess_letter))

I think it is using the above if and I'm unsure how to fix it. This is what the `while` loop looks like:

```
if guess_letter in list_of_letters:
    position = (word.index(guess_letter))
    print(hiding.replace(hiding[position], guess_letter))
    hiding = hiding.replace(hiding[position], guess_letter)
    correct_guess_amount += 1

while correct_guess_amount <len(word):
    if guess_letter in list_of_letters:
        guess_letter = input('enter a letter: ')
        position = (word.index(guess_letter))
        print(hiding.replace(hiding[position], guess_letter))
        hiding =  hiding.replace(hiding[position], guess_letter)
        correct_guess_amount += 1
        print(correct_guess_amount)
    elif guess_letter not in list_of_letters:
        incorrect_guess_amount += 1
        incorrect_list.append(guess_letter)
        print(incorrect_list)
        print(incorrect_guess_amount)
        guess_letter = input('enter a letter: ')
        if guess_letter in list_of_letters:
            guess_letter = input('enter a letter: ')
            position = (word.index(guess_letter))
            print(hiding.replace(hiding[position], guess_letter))
            hiding = hiding.replace(hiding[position], guess_letter)
            correct_guess_amount += 1
            print(correct_guess_amount)
```

Comment: the code under the second if is not indented

Comment: You could just use `else`; either the letter is in the list or it isn't.

Comment: you repeat the same code too many times. Inside `elif` you have if` which repeate the smae code but you could do it directly after `while` - like in answer @Allie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem arises from the fact that you are having the user input the guess **after** you have checked if the `guess_letter` is in the `word`. Your loop should look like

```py
while correct_guess_amount < len(word):
    guess_letter = input("...")
    if guess_letter in word:
        # now you can safely call word.index(guess_letter)
    else:
        # handle the wrong answer case
```

Comment: even while its indented, i still get the error

Comment: That would cause a IndentationError, not a ValueError. @Sundry: In that case, fix your question.

Comment: @Sundry what example are you using? What letter are you guessing to throw the error? What is the `list_of_letters` variable?

Comment: I'm using four letter words, the wrong letter im throwing in is z. list_of_letters is list(word) so i can find certain letters within the word you are trying to guess.

Comment: Thank you so much! works well and is much shorter.

Comment: @Sundry yay! No prob